# How to groupby year and unstack years into columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas, group-by, cumsum

I have a pandas time series `ser`

```
ser
>>>
date         x
2018-01-01   0.912
2018-01-02   0.704
...
2021-02-01   1.285
```

and I want to take a cumulative sum by year and make each year into a column as such, and the date index should now be just dates in year (e.g. Jan 01, Jan 02,... the formatting of Month and Day doesn't matter)

```
date     2018_x    2019_x    2020_x    2021_x    2022_x
Jan-01   0.912     ...       ...       ...       ...
Jan-02   1.616     ...       ...       ...       ...
...
```

I know how to groupby and take a cumulative sum, but then I want to do some sort of unstacking operation to get the years into columns

```
ser.groupby(ser.index.year).cumsum()
# what do I do next?
```

The standard pandas `unstack()` operation doesn't work here.

Can anyone please advise how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First you can aggregate `sum` per `MM-DD` with years and then reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = ser.groupby([ser.index.strftime('%m-%d'), ser.index.year]).sum().unstack(fill_value=0).cumsum()
print (df)
date    2018   2021
date               
01-01  0.912  0.000
01-02  1.616  0.000
02-01  1.616  1.285
```

Or if no duplicated datetimes create `MultiIndex` without `groupby`:

```
ser.index = [ser.index.strftime('%m-%d'), ser.index.year]

df = ser.unstack(fill_value=0).cumsum()
print (df)
date    2018   2021
date               
01-01  0.912  0.000
01-02  1.616  0.000
02-01  1.616  1.285
```